# Collapsed Categories - Interval or Ordinal Scale

Tags: categorical-data, ordinal-data, confirmatory-factor

Is it appropriate to treat the following indicator as having an interval scale:
"In the last two weeks, how many times have you been late for school:
1. Never (62% of respondents)
2. Once or twice (15% of respondents)
3. Three or four times (3% of respondents) 
4. Five or more times (2% of respondents). (18% missing). I lean towards interval as categories 2 and 3 have the same size and category four seems to be the limit for the sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you leave it as is, it's clearly ordinal, not interval, as the spacing between levels is not even. If you want to treat it as interval, then I would do the following:

1. Never  = 0
2. Once or twice = 1.5
3. Three or four times = 3.5
4. Five or more times = ???? Well, here you have to take a guess. But you know that the maximum is 10, and you haven't got a lot of people in the top category. If you put in 7.5, you probably won't be far off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm much more inclined to say this is an ordinal scale: the classes definitely have an order but you can't really perform operations like the mean on this set of results which would rule out interval scale - you can't say the difference between classes 1 and 2 is the same as between 3 and 4.